# Pass jQuery value to PHP function

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create gravatar auto load while user is writing his e-mail in a form field. Now, I've got php function, that will generate gravatar url with required paramaters and it work all over the website.

Now, when user types valid e-mail I should call jQuery:

```
image.attr("src", "<?=$this->Gravatar(" + input.attr('value') + ");?>");
```

But is this possible to pass this parameter to PHP function?

Comment: The thing is I don't want to create another request on my website ;) I just want to get the valid image URL. If it's not possible, the last step is ajax, I just wanted to know if I can skip it and pass it like that

Comment: The simple answer is, you can't. PHP runs on the server before the site is served up. JavaScript is executed on the client side once the PHP has been executed. Without an AJAX request, this is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood well you would like to do the following:

- User enters a vaild email
- Get the Gravatar from the PHP function without making an extrat request

You can't really perform this without any request to the server, but you can make an easier way

prepare a gateway script to call your PHP function and send it a param with get
should look something like:

```
http://YOUR-FULL-URL/getgravatar?email=use-email@example.com
```

than when the user enters an email you can get it this way

```
image.attr("src", "http://YOUR-FULL-URL/getgravatar?email=" + input.val() );
```

and like that you avoid using Ajax with a straight AJAX call

Answer (score 4):

You're going to need jQuery's [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) functionality. In your JavaScript, you'll need to see the value to an external PHP script which is expecting it.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.email').keyup(function() {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/path/to/your/script.php",
     data: { email: this.value }
   }).done(function( data ) {
     alert( data );
   });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // DB call - you'll need to replace with your own functionality
    // Make sure you sanitize input

    if (check_record_exists($_POST['email'])) {
       echo 'This e-mail is already being used';
    } else {
       echo 'This e-mail is fine';
    }
} else {
   echo 'No e-mail specified';
}
```